# how I can change URL on page refresh angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

let's say initially I am on page which has URL like "www.example.com/check/checkid  now when I refresh page I want the URL to be changed how I can do that in angular Js .

Comment: Do you want to redirect to another url? Or are you trying to mask the url?

Comment: There simply isn't enough information given to even guess at what you need or are trying to do. We don't even know where the root of your angular app is, what routing you are using etc

Comment: i want to redirect to another url but only when i refresh the page

Answer (score 2):

You can use $routeProvider, which is the provider of the $route service. This service makes it easy to wire together controllers, view templates, and the current URL location in the browser. 
I hope It will help.

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-routing-and-views-tutorial-with-example/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add a run block to do that, for example:

```
angular.module("myApp", [])

  .run(['$location', function($location) {
    // some logic
    $location.path("/somepath");
  }]);
```